# NSDictionary - stacking same id'ed elements into another Dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, nsdictionary

I have a Dictionary, this dictionary has values like :

edit: its not json, its dictionary directly

```
[{
    "personel_id" = 23;
    "task_id" = 125;
}, {
    "personel_id" = 34;
    "task_id" = 125;
}, {
    "personel_id" = 40;
    "task_id" = 126;
}]
```

i would like to group up the ones with the same task_id into an 2d Array or Dictionary - i don't know which one is better - which will be like

```
{
  "personel_id" = {23,34};
  "task_id" = 125
}
{
"personel_id" = 40;
    "task_id" = 126;
}
```

or

```
125 = {23,34}
126 = {40}
```

i ve tried so many things as far as i found on the internet but couldn't manage it.

Comment: please show what you tried

Comment: most of them was so out of context thats why i couldn't manage it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
let dec = JSONDecoder() 
dec.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase 
let res = try! dec.decode([Root].self, from: date) 
let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: res, by: { $0.taskId })
```

---

```
struct Root : Codable {
    let personalId, taskId : Int 
}
```

Comment: `.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase`, cool, never new about this!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found the answer which is :

```
let groupedDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: self.myDictionary) {
                (personel) -> String in
                return personel.value(forKey: "task_id") as! String
            }
```

i used grouping function, which worked fine.